# Can't run apt update on my computer

Tags: apt

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit:5 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Hit:8 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic InRelease      
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:10 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease [3,609 B]
Err:10 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
Fetched 3,609 B in 2s (1,561 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
384 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.riot.im/debian/dists/default/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone translate this to English? I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I don't remember how that got added, but I use the element app, so I assume I need it?

Comment: Should I remove it then? How might I go about that?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1469462/ for how to fix your expired key. Similar question for ROS, substitute appropriately.

Comment: Apt is not telling you about an Ubuntu problem. Apt is telling you about an Element problem. Since Element is commercial software, their support should be able to handle problems with their repositories, keys, and software.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll look elsewhere then, thanks.